# Finding MTD, QTD, and YTD in excel from monthly returns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've been working on this for awhile and can't seem to find an appropriate way to code this.

Goal: Take a list of monthly returns that currently spans over three years (this is an automated list so it will keep adding months) and find MTD, QTD, & YTD using function so I can automate the process.

Problem: I've tried the OFFSET function, different versions of COUNT, IF statements and can't find a way to properly code the function.

NOTE: this is for stock data/earnings report

Just to clarify, I know how to do this manually, but want to automate the process :) Would be more than happy to use VBA but would like to stick to a simple function if possible...

I'd be more than happy to email the WS to someone. Thanks so much!!

Comment: Do you have a sample format of the data to work with?  I forsee sumproduct being potentially a very good friend here.  That or some array formula of your choosing.  The only down side is that the number entries may bog down your calculation as your list grows.

Comment: Use PowerBI? That has time intelligence functions.

Comment: Use a lookup (date) table that maps days to months to quarters to years, match against that and pivot on that. They are always useful things to have lying around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep it simple and avoid vba here is a suggestion
The manner in which the data sheet is presented matters.
I assume months go down, with there only being 1 column for 'monthly returns'?

On a separate area/worksheet, set up the months with a value for what they are in the column next to them. Ie

```
Jan 1
Feb 2
Mar 3
Apr 4
...
Dec 12
```

then have a drop down where you can select what month it is.
so if it is Jul, you can select Jul.
From here, do a vlookup/indexmatch to pull the number for the month through, so Jul would be 7
From here the MTD is easy.
Do an offset from the beginning of the year to the current month

```
=offset ([start point],[month number],[columns])
=OFFSET($D$1,$C$21,0)
```

start point will be one row above Jan, that way when Jan is chosen it will fall onto Jan.
Month number you will get from what was said earlier
and columns will depend on how you place it

YTD, you will do the same as above but have a sum
so

```
=sum(B3:offset ([start point],[month number],[columns]))
=SUM(D2:OFFSET($D$1,C21,0))
```

QTD would be easiest just plotting the sums as it would never change
So set out Q1,Q2,Q3 and Q4 as prefixed ones. Then lookup to them.
However, if you want to see the most recent quarter by a formula. On the month number list add a new column which says what quarter it is. Then

```
Jan 1 1
Feb 2 1
Mar 3 1
Apr 4 2
...
Dec 12 4
```

It should the read off a formula like so

```
=SUM(
OFFSET([start point],(INDEX([month number table],MATCH([month],[month list],0),3)-1)*3,0):
OFFSET([start point],INDEX(month number table],MATCH([month],[month list],0),2),0))

=SUM(
OFFSET($D$2,(INDEX($F$2:$H$13,MATCH($C$20,$F$2:$F$13,0),3)-1)*3,0):
OFFSET($D$1,INDEX($F$2:$H$13,MATCH($C$20,$F$2:$F$13,0),2),0)
)
```

What you are doing is to find the month at the beginning of the quarter and then sum to the current month.

Regarding this bit at the end

```
OFFSET([start point],(INDEX([month number table],MATCH([month],[month list],0),3)-1)*3,0):
```

You are finding the month quarter index number(1,2,3,4) and multiplying it by three. The reason you want to take away one before multiplying by three is because you want the start point of the quarter, thus in jan to march, this will be 0, and then you add a row to get the start point being Jan.
In Oct to Dec this will be (4-1) = 3. 3x3 = 9 which will be Oct to make Oct being the start point. Amend as need be.

[image: Rough outline of the way it works]

The yellow section is what your actual information is presented as

The green section is your lookup area

The Blue area is information you are looking for with the lower bit reading from the lookup

Comment: QTD would change... Any idea on how to do this? I need everything to be automated so currently (july) the QTD would be the same as MTD (july is the start of Q3), however, when my excel sheet updated after july, i need QTD to include july and august... Thanks so much

Comment: Have a look at the amended comments, that should work. Any issues then please ask away

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I'm still a bit confused. How are you suggesting I set up my columns? Right now I have two columns, col1 is 12 rows. the 12th row is the current date, 11th row is current date - 1, and so on. Col-2 is the quarter number of each corresponding date in col1...WIth that being said, how do i implement your function? I think im confused on the start point and column numbers... Thank you so much!!

Comment: My understanding is your information that you receive is as such: Column A is your month name (Jan, Feb, Mar to Dec in that order). Column B is the value of the stock for the month(e.g. $1,000, $1,500 etc). Do you have headings for them such as month and value? If not, what cell is the first month in. So if your first one is Jan, and the value is $2,000.  Can you tell me what cell Jan is in, such as "A1" and I will amend my formulas for that

Comment: Again, thank you very much for your help... Here is the setup: Colum1 is the months so E31 = August 2017 & e32 is September (Jan is in d36) (going down the list to where we are now in july at cell E42.. i did this with the function: =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())-1, 1) so each one up is a previous of the month before...... Then from column1 I created a "quarter column" next to it in column f using the fuction =ROUNDUP(MONTH(E42)/3,0).... this returns columns 1 month into the corresponding quarter.... I have monthly returns in % in column 3.

Comment: jan is e36, no d

Comment: Ok, the problem with how you have it set up is that every month the first month will be different, thus you need a formula to capture it. As you do not have a lot of data (12x2), set up some new columns so the first month is January. Do an indexmatch if you must from the current data. That way you will be able to work easier. With your current info, it will always be changing and incredibly hard, or long winded, to be correct. Added picture to help

Comment: Can you rewrite the OFFSET function for the data shown above in the picture, please? Still not getting the correct answer

Comment: I added it for you, honestly, don't worry if you need to ask for more help.

Comment: Okay, so I replicated your test and got "35" for the month of July:) Only, question i have before closing out the question is regarding the testing of this. Is there any way I can test this methodology before a final submission? I attempted to manipulate the quarters but to no avail. Thanks!!

Comment: Add in data as you see it being, and then change the months around and make sure it is correct for the month, YTD and QTD